# how to get boolean as return value in typescript / angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a function in angular2 service as follow

```
 doNext() {
        if(value exists){   
            return true;
        }
        else{
           return false;
        }
    }
```

and i am calling it from comoponent as this

```
 if(this.myService.doNext){
//do next
}
else{
//stop
}
```

But its not working the way it should , it returns undefined or the code of `donNext()` function. can anyone help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually invoke the function:

```
 if(this.myService.doNext()) { // note parentheses
//do next
}
else{
//stop
}
```

Comment: i will try with this , let you know in a moment

Comment: hi its working but  `if(this.myService.doNext()) { // 
//do next` this should not work when `null` or `false` right but its still executing do next ... any idea??

Comment: That's not really a question

Comment: i mean when its returning a null value it should not execure // do next

Comment: sorry my bad ... was doing something stupid.. :) thanks a lot

Comment: why downvote my question and your answer is right i was just checking it on another page while had edited code at another page..